# Issue with FastCGI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, kohana

On my website I have a catalog page: `http://website.com/beads` and pagination links at the bottom of the page

Pagination links on my local server looks like `http://website.com/beads/page2`, `http://website.com/beads/page3`, etc.

On hosting it looks like `http://website.com/beads/page2?/beads=`, `http://website.com/beads/page3?/beads=` etc its bad even without additional filters(with it its getting horrible)

If I do on catalog page `debug::vars($this->request->query());`

On a local server it prints: `array(0)`

On a hosting: `array(1) ( "/beads" => string(0) "" )`

Hosting runs FastCGI, my route looks like:

```
Route::set('catalog', '<uri>(/page<page>)',
    array(
        'uri' => '[a-z0-9-]+', 
        'page' => '[0-9]+')
    )
    ->defaults(array( 
        'directory' => 'frontend',
        'controller' => 'catalog', 
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

.htaccess on local server and hosting is the same expept this:

Hosting: `RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]`

Local: `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]`

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Why are you using different rules? Obviously you will obtain different results using different rules. Also post the entire content of the `.htaccess`

Comment: This problem is in daemon configuration that listen 80 port. If local is apache and servers is nginx problem will be in it.